# Php Form Builder Framework Populate Form from Session

Tags: php, forms, builder, pfbc

I`m currently using the [PFBC framework](http://www.imavex.com/pfbc3.x-php5/) for setting up forms. I have a small checkout form that I need to post (step 1 ). Once validated and posted the form redirects to the next page (step 2).

I want to enable customers to change their form input when using the back button (browser).

Somehow I dont see to manage to pre populate the fields from the session. the form Classes are defined in form:php

```
$form = new Form("question");

// Prevent bootstrap and jquery from re-loading, already loaded in doc head
$form->configure(array("prevent" => array("jQuery"), "view" => new View_SideBySide, "labelToPlaceholder" => 0));
$form->addElement(new Element_Hidden("form", "question"));

$form->addElement(new Element_HTML('<hr />'));
$form->addElement(new Element_Select("Type:", "type", $options, array("ID" => "type", "class" => "form-control", "required" => 1, "data-placeholder" => "Kies een type")));
$form->addElement(new Element_Textbox("Titel:", "title", array("ID" => "title", "class" => "form-control", "required" => 1, "placeholder" => "Geef hier een duidelijke titel op")));
$form->addElement(new Element_Button("Verstuur", "submit", array("ID" => "submit")));
$form->addElement(new Element_HTML('hr />'));

$form->render();
echo $id;
//----------AFTER THE FORM HAS BEEN SUBMITTED----------
if ($_POST["form"] == 'question') {
    //ADDITIONELE VALUES

    //UNSET VALUES THAT DONT BELONG IN THE DB
    unset($_POST["form"]);
    //ENTER DATA INTO DB
    //$api->dbSave('application', $_POST);

    //$id  = mysql_insert_id();
    //$_SESSION['formpost'] = $id;

    //CLEAR VALUES AND REDIRECT
    Form::clearValues("question");

    header("location: " . $this->root . "next-page/step-2/");
}
```